# How do I change the order of my divs in mobile view?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

In this example, I would like my image column to stack below the text info column in mobile view. How would I achieve this?

I tried using flexbox but had I no luck, would be much appreciated if somebody could explain this to me. Thankyou

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
            <img src="img/buy1.png" class="img-fluid phone1" width="300" height="auto" alt="buy icon">
        </div>

      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
        <div class="info-container">
            <div class="purchase-icon-left">
                <img src="img/buy-icon.png" class="purchase-icon" alt="buy icon">
            </div>

            <div class="text-test2">
                <h1 class="title">SEEK</h1><h2 class="not-bold">and you will find.</h2>
                  <ul>
                        <li>Discover your desired items by browsing through eight different categories.</li>
                        <li>Browse through thousands of items sold by other users. </li>
                        <li>Don't agree with the price? Message the seller and request a price deduction. </li>
                  </ul> 
            </div>

       </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: tried changing `flex-direction` on `row`?

Comment: Are you using Bootstrap 3 or 4?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use display:flex and order. Change number of order to change position on screen.
Moreover you need to have media query for smaller screen. In order to see all effect check it on full page and drag the screen.

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 750px) { 
    .row{
        display:flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        flex-flow: row wrap;
  
    }
  div.text-test2{
    background:red;
    order: 1;
  }
  .col-lg-4{
    background:green;
    order: 2;
  }

.purchase-icon-left{
    background:blue;
    order: 3;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-12">
            <img src="http://tineye.com/images/widgets/mona.jpg" class="img-fluid phone1" width="300" height="auto" alt="buy icon">
        </div>

      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-12">
        <div class="info-container">
            <div class="purchase-icon-left">
                <img src="http://tineye.com/images/widgets/mona.jpg" class="purchase-icon" alt="buy icon">
            </div>

            <div class="text-test2">
                <h1 class="title">SEEK</h1><h2 class="not-bold">and you will find.</h2>
                  <ul>
                        <li>Discover your desired items by browsing through eight different categories.</li>
                        <li>Browse through thousands of items sold by other users. </li>
                        <li>Don't agree with the price? Message the seller and request a price deduction. </li>
                  </ul> 
            </div>

       </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the code below.

At first, the image is above the text, but once the width is below 400px it jumps to below the text. To do this, it uses the two classes `.computer-only` and `.mobile-only`, which are defined in the CSS using a `@media` query.

```css
.mobile-only {
  display: none;
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {

  .mobile-only {
    display: block;
  }

  .computer-only {
    display: none;
  }
  
}
```

```html
<img class="computer-only" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.svg?v=a010291124bf">

Welcome to stackoverflow!

<img class="mobile-only" src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/stackoverflow/company/img/logos/so/so-logo.svg?v=a010291124bf">
```

To apply this to your example, ignore the HTML code but add the CSS to your styles. You can then add the two classes to any elements you need.

Also, change the `400px` to whatever you define as the boundary between mobile and computer!